# Passing PHP variables between different code segments on same page

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to write a custom archiving script for my senior project and I am having some issues. I have two issues:

1)  I would like to make it so that the folders themselves are not links, but instead are highlighted with a color of my choosing when they are selected.

2)  Once the folder is highlighted, I would like to take the path of that selected folder and save it to a variable that is accessible from anywhere on that page.  I will use that path as an upload directory for my dropbox for uploading or manual upload.  Showing the most current highlight directory is to help the user know where they are within the file structure, and to help me troubleshoot.  Below is the code for my file tree.

```
function ListFolder($path)
{
    //using the opendir function
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

    //Leave only the lastest folder name
    $dirname = end(explode("/", $path));

    //display the target folder.
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<label for='folder1'>$dirname</label>  <input type='checkbox' id='folder1' />";

    echo "<ol>";
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) 
    {
        if($file!="." && $file!="..")
        {
            if (is_dir($path."/".$file))
            {
                //Display a list of sub folders.
                ListFolder($path."/".$file);
            }
            else
            {
                //Display a list of files.
                echo "<li class='file'><a href='$path/$file'>$file</a></li>";
                echo "<li>";
                echo $path;

            }
        }
    }
    echo "</ol>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";

    //closing the directory
    closedir($dir_handle);
}
```

If there is an easier way to do this, any help would be appreciated.  This is my first time writing something like this and I am stumped.